# Unpivot messy table

Tags: sql-server

I have a messy table in SQL Server (sorry, this is how I get it from a vendor). I have dumbed it down considerably so that I can focus on the problem, though I am clearly losing sight of the forest for the trees.

**Objective**: sort of UNPIVOT this data, though I cannot seem to get the logic just right.
**Issue**: The quirk is that I need a substring of the column header as part of the data - as you can see in the sample below.

Rextester sample data http://rextester.com/live/PHXT48379

My table, once imported looks like this:

```
+----+----------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| id |  person  | contact 1 - phone  | contact 2 - phone  | contact 1 - email | contact 2 - email |
+----+----------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1 | john doe |             123456 |             234567 | john@doe.me       | johndoe@gmail.com |
|  2 | jane doe |             654321 |             765432 | Jane@doe.me       | NULL              |
+----+----------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Intended output:

```
+----+----------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
| id |  person  | contactNumber | phone  |       email       |
+----+----------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
|  1 | John Doe |             1 | 123456 | john@doe.me       |
|  1 | John Doe |             2 | 234567 | johndoe@gmail.com |
|  2 | Jane Doe |             1 | 654321 | jane@doe.me       |
|  2 | Jane Doe |             2 | 765432 | janedoe@gmail.com |
+----+----------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case you need to go "Dynamic" in the sense you don't know how may columns (or contacts)

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([id] varchar(50),[person] varchar(50),[contact 1 - phone] varchar(50),[contact 2 - phone] varchar(50),[contact 1 - email] varchar(50),[contact 2 - email] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'john doe',123456,234567,'john@doe.me','johndoe@gmail.com')
,(2,'jane doe',654321,765432,'Jane@doe.me',NULL)


Select id
      ,person
      ,contactNumber
      ,phone  = max(case when Item like '%phone%' then value end)
      ,email  = max(case when Item like '%email%' then value end)
 From (
        Select A.ID
              ,A.Person
              ,contactNumber = cast(substring(Item,patindex('%[0-9]%',item),2) as int)
              ,C.*
         From @YourTable A
         Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
         Cross Apply (
                        Select Item  = replace(a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)'),'_x0020_',' ')
                              ,Value = a.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                         From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                         Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
                         Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('id','person')
                     ) C
      )  A
 Group By id,person,contactNumber
```

**Returns**

[image]

> **EDIT - Simplified**

```
Select A.ID
      ,A.Person
      ,C.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item  = replace(a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)'),'_x0020_',' ')
                      ,Value = a.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
                 Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('id','person')
             ) C
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: I will need to go dynamic - so this seems to make sense. Still need to digest this. I like the way many of your answers (have come across a fair share) all use the same tool - cast as XML, CROSS APPLY the nodes.

Comment: @Eli As you know, SQL Server is declarative by design.  You certainly go classic DYNAMIC SQL (which may be more performant), but what I like about the XML approach is there is no scope issues and the XML / source can be a table, view, or even a custom query with derived columns.  For example I have a Table-Value function which will convert virtually any select into an EAV structure.  Being a TVF, it can be incorporated into a CROSS APPLY or consumed by another query.

Comment: I tried to implement your concept into the real data set, however, I encountered some issues wherein the "contactnumber" field was bringing back non-numeric values, and they were breaking the query on a failed conversion etc. I added all the fields which I don't want "unpivoted" into the "not in" piece inside the second cross apply, to no avail :(

Comment: @Eli Clearly we have some unexpected values/formats in the column names.  See EDIT Simplified version.  Perhaps that will aid in task / development

Comment: That's where I started off... I need the value following the word "contact". I tried editing your line of ` Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('id','person')` to have all fields which don't begin with contact, though it is still picking up some values...

Comment: @Eli thats why we have ,contactNumber = cast(substring(Item,patindex('%[0-9]%',item),2) as int)  ... do you have contact fields without a number?

Comment: @Eli rather than NON IN () you could have LIKE '%contact%[0-9]%'

Comment: @Eli I would need to see a the list of column names so I could see which ones break the pattern  Contact # - xxx

Comment: @Eli Just dawned on me.  Perhaps this will help   Where replace(a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)'),'_x0020_',' ') like '%contact%[0-9]%'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154540/discussion-between-eli-and-john-cappelletti).

Comment: switching from NOT LIKE to LIKE somehow did the trick - not missing any fields, so I'm good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just the use `UNION` to produce all records for contact 1 and all records for contact 2 if contact 2 has either or an email or phone that is not null.  Use `COALESCE` to use contact-1's email if the email for contact-2 is null.

```
SELECT id, person, 1 [contactNumber], [contact 1 - phone] [phone], [contact 1 - email] [email]
FROM #TEST

UNION

SELECT id, person, 2
  , [contact 2 - phone]
  , COALESCE([contact 2 - email], [contact 1 - email])
FROM #TEST
WHERE [contact 2 - phone] IS NOT NULL OR [contact 2 - email] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I want contact number 2 to show up, though if it isn't there, I want a NULL - coalesce will give me the first one again - I don't want that.

Comment: Ok.  I changed my answer so that Phone will be null.

Comment: With the `COALESCE`, it is still showing the first contact email address if the second one is `NULL`

Comment: That's how your example in your question works.  Feel free to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    person,
    1 as contactnumber, 
    [contact 1 - phone] as phone, 
    [contact 1 - email] as email 
FROM Table
UNION
SELECT 
    id, 
    person,
    2 as contactnumber, 
    [contact 2 - phone] as phone, 
    [contact 2 - email] as email 
FROM Table
```

Comment: You forgot the FROM clause

Comment: Also, it's essentially the same as my answer.

Comment: FROM clause added